# Froala Java SDK: Upload Image doesn't work

Tags: java, froala

Uplaod image with Froala java sdk doesn't work, got this error:

> java.lang.Exception: Fieldname is not correct. It must be: file

I'm using spring framework. This is my code:

```
@RestController
public class SoutienController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/enregistrerImage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void enregistrerImage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        Map<Object, Object> responseData;
        ImageOptions options = new ImageOptions();
        options.setFieldname("file");
        try {
            String fileRoute = "/images/";
            responseData = Image.upload(request, fileRoute, options);
            System.out.println("OK");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            responseData = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
            responseData.put("error", e.toString());
        }
        String jsonResponseData = new Gson().toJson(responseData);
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        try {
            response.getWriter().write(jsonResponseData);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I configure MultiPart in web.xml:

```
<multipart-config>
        <max-file-size>20848820</max-file-size>
        <max-request-size>418018841</max-request-size>
        <file-size-threshold>1048576</file-size-threshold>
    </multipart-config>
```

And in spring-context.xml:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        </bean>
```

So I checked the HttpServletRequest with

```
request.getParts() = []
```

But when I put in parameter

```
public void enregistrerImage(@RequestBody Multipart file, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
```

I have this file as Multipart.

So why the request have none Part while the requestBody have one ?

Tell me if it's not clear :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found another way to make it works with the source of Examples in froala SDK, but I have to make some changes in the froala SDK files:

[Froala Editor Java sdk Examples don't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42899071/froala-editor-java-sdk-examples-dont-work)